# How to display methods in the console that read from a file?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to be able to display the Average, ColumnTotal, Highest/Lowest in row, RowTotal. I'm not sure whether it depends on something I did in the methods themselves that has to be changed, or if I can simply that call them with the correct arguments to read from a file. The text file that it reads from basically just inputs two integers that are separated by a space on the same line, those are the arguments I would like to be able to input. I'm not entirely sure how to do this. This is just an assignment from a College text book basically amped up by my Instructor called "TwoDimArray" which I've been able to find many examples of online but none of them had the 'read from file' portion that I have to do here, they all just used a normal array input such as "int[][] array = {{22, 37, 48, 68}} for the main method. I'm going to include the entire program in order to show exactly what I need to be displayed via println.  I've been thinking about how to do this for quite a few hours now and decided that I definitely need help. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks ahead of time.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimArray {

private int arr[][];

public TwoDimArray() {
    loadArray();
}

public void loadArray(){
    /**
     * loadArray() method loads user defined filename
     * @return text file's contents
     */
    String fileName = "";
    try {
        fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter file name: ");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "can not open " + fileName + " to read");
        return;
    }
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        int rows, cols;
        rows = in.nextInt();
        cols = in.nextInt();
        arr = new int[rows][cols];
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
                arr[i][j] = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "can not open " + fileName + " to read");
    }
}

public int getArrayMaxValue(){
    /**
     * @return the max vale of the array
     */
    int maxVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; ++j){
            if(arr[i][j] > maxVal){
                maxVal = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return maxVal;
}

public int getArrayMinValue(){
    /**
     * @return the minimum value of the array
     */
    int minVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; ++j){
            if(arr[i][j] < minVal){
                minVal = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return minVal;
}

public static int getTotal(int[][] array) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
            total += array[row][col];
        }
    }

    return total;
}

public static int getAverage(int[][] array) {
    return getTotal(array) / getElementCount(array);
}

public static int getRowTotal(int[][] array, int row) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
        total += array[row][col];
    }

    return total;
}

public static int getColumnTotal(int[][] array, int col) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        total += array[row][col];
    }

    return total;
}

public static int getHighestInRow(int[][] array, int row) {
    int highest = array[row][0];

    for (int col = 1; col < array[row].length; col++) {
        if (array[row][col] > highest) {
            highest = array[row][col];
        }
    }
    return highest;
}

public static int getLowestInRow(int[][] array, int row) {
    int lowest = array[row][0];

    for (int col = 1; col < array[row].length; col++) {
        if (array[row][col] < lowest) {
            lowest = array[row][col];
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}

public static int getElementCount(int[][] array) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        count += array[row].length;
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
/**
* what to put in int[][] array to allow println of average, getrowtotal, 
* etc..
*/
    int[][] array = ???;

    TwoDimArray twoDimArray = new TwoDimArray();
    System.out.println("Max value: " + twoDimArray.getArrayMaxValue());
    System.out.println("Min value: " + twoDimArray.getArrayMinValue());
    System.out.println(getAverage(array));
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0) Create `numbers.txt` in the root of your project. This is the file you will load array from. Example content as follows (2 rows, 3 columns):

```
2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

1) You don't need your explicitly created `int[][] array = ???` because there is already existing `private int arr[][]` which will be automatically loaded from file after you type it's name as intended in `TwoDimArray` constructor.

[image: input example]

2) Since `main` method located at the same class as `private int arr[][]`, you can access this private array without public getter/setter, and get average value like this:

```
// you don't need following line at all
// int[][] array = ???;

TwoDimArray twoDimArray = new TwoDimArray();

System.out.println("Max value: " + twoDimArray.getArrayMaxValue()); // Max value: 5
System.out.println("Min value: " + twoDimArray.getArrayMinValue()); // Min value: 1

// Average value
System.out.println(getAverage(twoDimArray.arr)); // 3, because 21 / 6 = 3
```

3) You probably got confused because `getArrayMaxValue` is signed as `public int`, and got invoked as `twoDimArray.getArrayMaxValue()`, whereas `getAverage` is `public static int` and must be called in different way.

I suggest marking `getAverage` as `public int` instead of `public static int`, and use `private int arr[][]` instead of `int[][] array` provided from arguments, so you will be able to call it the same way you do with other methods:

```
// Somewhere up
public int getAverage() {
    return getTotal(arr) / getElementCount(arr);
}

// In your main method
System.out.println(twoDimArray.getAverage());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That was extremely helpful in many ways. Unfortunately my upvotes don't count as public yet, but I did upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you have there is a jagged array, it is not a bidimensional array. I will explain you the idea, you do the rest. That it is not a bidimensional array. This is an array of array, in each position you are pointing to a new array of int. If you never instantiated a new array on each position, then you have a position with a null value.

[image]

So going back with your question, you should read the entire line with the two integers that are on the same line. Be sure that the line in your file has in the first line 2 numbers separated by a space.
Then use the `next()` method to get the complete string

```
String line = in.next();
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
int val1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
int val2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

For this question:
**what to put in int[][] array to allow println of average, getrowtotal,**

```
int[][] array = new int[4];
array[0] = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50};
array[1] = new int[] {60,71,80,90,91};
array[2] = new int[] {1};
```

Hope this helps

Now, what do you think you have in array[3]? The answer is: NULL

Comment: I appreciate your input! I didn't realize there was a null array[3], so this definitely gives me a deeper understanding of the code. Definitely great input for someone as new to coding as I am.

Answer (score 0):

you already read the array from file in your method loadArray...
Use it instead of trying to load the same thing again, remove static modifier from all method and use field arr instead of parameter array

```
private int getTotal() {
    int total = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++) {
            total += arr[row][col];
        }
    }

    return total;
}

private int getAverage() {
    return getTotal() / getElementCount();
}


private int getElementCount() {
    int count = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        count += arr[row].length;
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TwoDimArray twoDimArray = new TwoDimArray();
    System.out.println("Max value: " + twoDimArray.getArrayMaxValue());
    System.out.println("Min value: " + twoDimArray.getArrayMinValue());
    System.out.println(twoDimArray.getAverage());
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, than what I was trying to do. I honestly wasn't sure where I was trying to go with my main method. Thank you for clarifying that I don't need int[][] array. This way definitely makes much more sense.